# How to create and request certificates with the type "Apple Development" or "Apple Distribution" with official App Store Connect API?

Tags: ios, api, app-store-connect

I am using or try to use the [official App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi) to create bundle identifiers, profiles etc. But currently in v1 / v1.1 there is one important detail missing:

The newly introduced [certificate types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/certificatetype) "Apple Development" and "Apple Distribution" are not available through this official API.

Is any one out there who was able to access the api and got it to work with the new certificate types which are currently not documented?

Due to the fact that those certificate types are mandatory when using Xcode 11.x I hope you can help me.

I also created some feedbacks @ apple. Wrote some emails to apple. But no answer yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a few days and a handful of radars back and furth it is NOW possible to request the new certificate types "DISTRIBUTION" and "DEVELOPMENT" via the AppStoreConnect API!

In order to have a working codable struct you should support the newly added CertificateTypes "DISTRIBUTION" and "DEVELOPMENT".

As usually the documentation is still not up to date but due to a crashing request in my application I was keen enough to look again :)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/certificatetype